# Is there jQuery,mentionsId edit option?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I am using mentions input jquery for my text area for mentioning names like facebook.
When I try to edit the mentioned text, already mentioned name changes to plaintext. How can I handle this?

Comment: By using some amount of code I guess! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no such option, jQuery is a JavaScript Library, which you can implement for your own usage.

You cannot just ask jQuery to do your own work. You need to code it out!

When Facebook uses this feature, they actually try to use it like `[userId:userName]` which would be changed back to the Name and the Link to their profile.

I would ask you to do the same, when a user edit the names, replace that text fully. Don't just append it, just replace it as a whole. This way, the plaintext wouldn't be written and the mentionsId would have the new Name mentioned inside it.